# NHibernate UpdateBuilder.Set create lambda expression by propery info c#

Tags: c#, lambda, nhibernate

I want to create generic lambda expression according to property info

```
 var pInfo = typeof(User).GetProperty("Counter");
 var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(User), @"source");
 var property = Expression.Property(parameter, pInfo);
 var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<User, object>>(property, parameter); // this line 
 //should be created according to the property type
//Expression.Lambda<Func<User, int>>
//Expression.Lambda<Func<User, string>>
//Expression.Lambda<Func<User, bool>>

//update fields in db nhibernate
updateBuilder.Set(lambda, Convert.ChangeType(pu.Value, pInfo.PropertyType, null));
```

Is there a way to create lambda expression when type is unknown without if syntax for each property?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not 100% sure what exactly you are trying to do, may be you should edit the question to explain in details.

But, following function will give you the generic lambda from property name as string. You can easily extract string name from property info. Hope this helps you.

```
public static Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> GetLambdaFromString<TEntity>(string property) where TEntity : BaseEntity
{
    var x = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "x");
    var body = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Convert
                (
                    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(x, property), typeof(object)
                );
    var lambda = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, object>>(body, x);
    return lambda;
}
```